# BFS for islands in a graph returns empty vectors

Tags: c++, vector, openmp, breadth-first-search

I have the following function

```
vector<uint8_t> ConnectedComponents() {
    vector<uint8_t> independent_nodes;
    vector<bool> Visited(NumVertices, false);
    for (uint8_t vertex = 0; vertex < NumVertices; vertex++) {
        if (!Visited[vertex]) {
            Visited[vertex] = true;
            independent_nodes.push_back(vertex);
            vector<int16_t> Parent(this->BFSParent(vertex));
            for (uint8_t i = 0; i < NumVertices; i++) {
                if (Parent[i] != -1)
                    Visited[i] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return independent_nodes;
}
```

which is returning an empty vector. The `if` statement must have been true at least once.

This is a method for a struct `BFS`. `NumVertices` contains the number of vertices that are in the graph.

Here is the `BFSParent` function

```
vector<int16_t> BFSParent(uint8_t Start) {
    TSQueue Q;
    Q.push(Start);
    vector<bool> Visited(NumVertices, false);
    Visited[Start] = true;
    vector<int16_t> Prev(NumVertices, -1);

    while (Q.push_pointer != Q.pop_pointer) {
        uint8_t Node = Q.pop();
        vector<pair<uint8_t, uint8_t>> Neighbours(AdjacencyList[Node]);
#pragma omp for schedule(guided)
        for (auto i : Neighbours) {
            if (!Visited[i.first]) {
                // Does not matter what order the next layer's vertices are
                // added to the queue, just that they are
                Q.push(i.first);
                Visited[i.first] = true;
                Prev[i.first] = Node;
            }
        }
    }
    return Prev;
}
```

Here are the definitions of `TSQueue` and `Graph`. `Graph` is inherited publicly by the struct `BFS`

```cpp
struct TSQueue {
    uint64_t push_pointer = 0;
    uint64_t pop_pointer = 0;
    static constexpr uint64_t capacity = 1 << 8;
    vector<uint8_t> ts_queue;
    TSQueue() { this->ts_queue.resize(capacity); }
    void push(uint8_t node) {
// this pragma prevents the variables in the scope from being copied to
// L1 cache
    #pragma omp critical
        {
            this->ts_queue[push_pointer] = node;
            push_pointer++;
        }
    }
    uint8_t pop() {
        uint8_t var = this->ts_queue[pop_pointer];
        pop_pointer++;
        return var;
    }
};

struct Graph {

    // number of nodes
    uint8_t NumVertices;

    // Adjacency List
    vector<vector<pair<uint8_t, uint8_t>>> AdjacencyList;

    // Constructor
    Graph(uint8_t v) : NumVertices(v), AdjacencyList(v){};

    // Add an additional edge to the adjacency list
    void AddEdge(uint8_t Src, uint8_t Dst, int16_t Weight) {
        AdjacencyList[Dst].push_back(pair<uint8_t, int16_t>(Src, Weight));
        AdjacencyList[Src].push_back(pair<uint8_t, int16_t>(Dst, Weight));
    }
};
```

Here is the full struct `BFS` (contains a lot of code irrelevant to the question)

```cpp
struct BFS : public Graph {

    BFS(uint8_t vertices) : Graph(vertices){};
    // Navigate the Graph and store parents of each node in a vector being
    // returned
    vector<int16_t> BFSParent(uint8_t Start) {
        TSQueue Q;
        Q.push(Start);
        vector<bool> Visited(NumVertices, false);
        Visited[Start] = true;
        vector<int16_t> Prev(NumVertices, -1);

        while (Q.push_pointer != Q.pop_pointer) {
            uint8_t Node = Q.pop();
            vector<pair<uint8_t, uint8_t>> Neighbours(AdjacencyList[Node]);
#pragma omp for schedule(guided)
            for (auto i : Neighbours) {
                if (!Visited[i.first]) {
                    // Does not matter what order the next layer's vertices are
                    // added to the queue, just that they are
                    Q.push(i.first);
                    Visited[i.first] = true;
                    Prev[i.first] = Node;
                }
            }
        }
        return Prev;
    }

    // Navigate the Graph and store parents of each node in a vector being
    // returned
    bool BFSCycle(uint8_t Start) {
        TSQueue Q;
        Q.push(Start);
        vector<bool> Visited(NumVertices, false);
        Visited[Start] = true;
        vector<int16_t> Prev(NumVertices, -1);
        bool flag = false;
        while (Q.push_pointer != Q.pop_pointer) {
            uint8_t Node = Q.pop();
            vector<pair<uint8_t, uint8_t>> Neighbours(AdjacencyList[Node]);
#pragma omp for schedule(guided)
            for (auto next : Neighbours) {
                if (!Visited[next.first]) {
                    // Does not matter what order the next layer's vertices are
                    // added to the queue, just that they are
                    Q.push(next.first);
                    Visited[next.first] = true;
                    Prev[next.first] = Node;
                } else if (Node != Prev[next.first])
                    flag = true;
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }

    // Reconstruct the path for shortest route assuming it is not weighted
    vector<uint8_t> ReconstructPath(uint8_t Src, uint8_t Dst,
                                    vector<int16_t> Prev) {
        vector<uint8_t> Path;
        for (int16_t i = Dst; i != -1; i = Prev[i]) {
            Path.push_back(i);
        }
        if (!Path.empty() && *(Path.rbegin()) == Src)
            return Path;
        return vector<uint8_t>(0);
    }

    vector<uint8_t> ConnectedComponents() {
        vector<uint8_t> independent_nodes;
        vector<bool> Visited(NumVertices, false);
        for (uint8_t vertex = 0; vertex < NumVertices; vertex++) {
            if (!Visited[vertex]) {
                Visited[vertex] = true;
                independent_nodes.push_back(vertex);
                vector<int16_t> Parent(this->BFSParent(vertex));
                for (uint8_t i = 0; i < NumVertices; i++) {
                    if (Parent[i] != -1)
                        Visited[i] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return independent_nodes;
    }

    bool HasCycle() {
        vector<uint8_t> Nodes(this->ConnectedComponents());
        bool result = false;
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(guided) reduction(| : result)
        for (auto node : Nodes)
            if (BFSCycle(node))
                result = result | true;
        return result;
    }
};
```

`main` function definition here

```cpp
int main() {

    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

    uint8_t num;

    cin >> num;

    BFS graph(num);

    int16_t dummy;
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        for (uint8_t j = 0; j < num; j++) {
            cin >> dummy;
            if (dummy != 0) {
                graph.AddEdge(i, j, dummy);
            }
        }
    }

    auto begin = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        for (uint j = i + 1; j < num; j++) {
            vector<int16_t> Path = graph.BFSParent(i);
            graph.ReconstructPath(i, j, Path);
        }
    }

    auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    cout << "Path computation: "
         << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count()
         << " µs" << endl;

    begin = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto v = graph.ConnectedComponents();
    for (auto &i : v)
        cout << i;

    end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    cout << "Checks for cycles: "
         << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count()
         << " µs" << endl;
}
```

I expected to have the elements of the vector there. However, the return value is an empty vector as no output is being produced.

Comment: "The `if` statement must have been true at least once." Not if `NumVertices` is zero. What input are you testing with?